# Preview Fails to render zoom properly for large png

Tags: macos, preview, graphics

I made a 32768 × 32768 pixel Mandelbrot png, because it's a fun thing to do.

It renders fine in preview, until I attempt to zoom in (which is the whole point of making the image as big as I made it). [image: Unzoomed]

When I do attempt to zoom in, it starts to grey out the rest of the image, and if I zoom out again, the rest of the image grays out. [image: Greying out]

It doesn't ever load. Is there a recommended way that I could render this large image?

**[SPECS]**

- 2017 15" MBP
- 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 1536MB
- Radeon Pro 555 2048 MB
- Image format: .png
- Image resolution: 32,768 x 32,768 pixels
- Image file size: 49MB

Comment: Would you be able to share the file via Dropbox or similar?

Comment: I agree - providing a link to somewhere we can download the file from would be a great way to troubleshoot this. Also, can you further clarify your graphics card? That is, you mention the Intel HD Graphics, but haven't clarified whether your MBP has the AMD Radeon Pro 555 or AMD Radeon Pro 560 as its dedicated GPU?

Comment: What software did the render / png? Can we get the file to try out?

Comment: I've experienced this as well even with PDF files in El Capitan.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j6ES7QwbFT354rsqtAzigVmEZnGHbwxH

Comment: It was generated by a golang program that I wrote.

Comment: @DerekHalden Cool. But is there really a reason ever to use an image that size. Anything that requires an image that size can most likely be split up into many smaller images.

Comment: @JBis, That's probably the better way to go about this, and certainly if I had more free time I would write a different program that worked that way. But that's a lot more complicated, and harder to put together than the version that I have.

Monomeeth AMD Radeon Pro 555

Answer (score 3):

I would try to open the image in a brand new user account, you can set that up in System Preferences > Users & Groups or just use the Guest account. If you see different results here it must be something in your profile interfering with Preview.

But I'm betting the preview developers didn't account much for people opening 49MB, 32kx32k images. In the likely chance that this is a genuine glitch you could quickly report it at https://www.apple.com/feedback/ or sign up for a developer account & do a full bug report over at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.

In the short term I would recommend trying to use a different application to view this. A browser or photo editing application might be a good fit. For an image like this there is also a good chance that JPEG would more efficiently compress it & cause less issues, maybe look into converting it with Photoshop or similar.

Comment: It took long enough to generate the first time, that I'm not sure I want to try generating it as a different file format.

Comment: You definitely do not want a Mandelbrot picture in a lossy format such as JPEG.

Comment: Tried opening in a different account with no luck, will file feedback.

Comment: Have you checked out a different application that can open PNG? Safari may even render this correctly

Comment: I have tried using a browser to open this. Xee from the comment by unknowndomain successfully renders and zooms in, but costs money.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the file and was able to reproduce the issue you describe, as others have mentioned you should report this to Apple as a bug.

However in the interim there is a nice little utility called [Xee](https://theunarchiver.com/xee) it still takes a lot of time to render but it works eventually, the app is £3.99 for the full version but there is a time limited trial on the website.

Within Xee, I set View > Scaling Quality to Low to improve loading times.

Example of 100% crop:
[image: example of 100% crop of the image in Xee]

Comment: This is certainly the closest I've seen to a solution for the problem, but it feels a shame to spend a ton on a computer only to have to spend more on an application that shows what I want.

Comment: I mean this is an unusual situation and as mentioned above. Reporting it to Apple will help but it’s going to take time. I don’t see there is any other solution.

Comment: @DerekHalden Just wondering if this answers your question?

Comment: I'm going to leave the bounty open for a little longer, just because it misses the mark a little in that it's a temporary solution (free trial limited to 30 days).

If nothing better comes up you will get the bounty.

Comment: I wasn’t really asking about the bounty but what the problem was. I understand now. I will have a think if there are other solutions.

Comment: Just of note I managed to open it in Adobe Photoshop CC 2018 just fine and zoom around, one thing I noted was that the PNG has an alpha channel so I removed this for testing, and same issue, but now the boxes are now black, which is the predominant background colour, where as before it was grey, which is actually just transparent. This is kind of leaning towards perhaps a memory issue where the rescaling algorithm is reading the same section of the image over and over again when trying to draw the scaled image.

Comment: Further to this thinking I drew some patterns onto the image so that it would be obvious if this was the issue, and these patterns didn't repeat, and the colour didn't affect the colour of the blocks which are still black on this image now that I've remove transparency. I am at a loss what else to suggest.

Answer (score -4):

Not enough power; suppose so. I think your problem can not be solved.